# Integrating a vector field over curve in R^2 with differential forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Sorry if this has been asked elsewhere; I know there are several questions on differential forms but I couldn't find the answer I am looking for.

Imagine I have a vector field $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and I want to integrate it over a curve $c:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2.$ I can define the form $\omega = F_1\, dx + F_2\, dy$, where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the $x$ and $y$ components of $F$, respectively, then I can compute
$$\displaystyle \int_c \omega = \int_{[0,1]} c^{*} \omega$$
which I am happy to do.

Suppose now I have a smooth $1$-manifold $M.$ A differential form on $M$ is defined to be a map $\omega$ such that $\omega (p) \in \Lambda ^k (M_p)$, where $M_p$ denotes the tangent space of $M$ at $p$. Since $M$ is a $1$-manifold, $M_p$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space, and therefore $\Lambda^1(M_p)$ is as well. How then could we define, much less integrate, a $1$-form like $F_1\, dx + F_2 \, dy$ on $M$?

More generally, if I have a smooth $k$-manifold, it seems to me that we can only define forms with $\omega(p) \in \Lambda^r (\mathbb{R}^k)$ unless we explicitly embed the manifold into a higher dimensional space.

Comment: Yes to define $F_1dx+F_2dy$ on your 1-manifold you assume it is an embedded sub manifold thus $dx$ actually means $i^*dx$

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's pretty straightforward.